# How to bind Jenkins build output with tests result?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, docker, protractor, docker-compose

I'm setting automated `protractor` tests to run in a `docker` container with the help of `jenkins`. But not been able to make a the `jenkins` build result to reflect the testing outcome (if some test fail, build should fail also).

Important to say that all tests should run, even if the first one fails.

The tests are initiated with `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` and my docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  protractor:
    volumes:
      - ./reporting:/assets/reporting
    image: protractor-test
    command: "dockerize -wait http://selenium:4444 -timeout 60m protractor /assets/conf.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your docker-compose command is returning exit code 0 no matter what.

How about using a [Jasmine xunit reporter](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters#protractor) to generate a test report, copy the generated xml test report to outside the container (using `docker cp`), and then publish it using Jenkins' [post-build action](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)?

The job will be marked as failed if the xml is not present, which means there's an error during the test runtime or it will be marked as unstable, if it has failed any of the test asserts.